# Calling web service returns The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to call a web service in C# using WSDL proxy, the web service requires credentials to be passed

```
PartsInquiryServiceHttpService client = new PartsInquiryServiceHttpService();
        client.Url = "Url";
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user Name", "password");
```

In this line an exception is thrown

```
client.getMultiplePartsInquiry(enquiry);
```

unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll  Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway

Please help

Comment: Check out the actual `ex.Response` property on your `catch(WebException ex)`, you could probably see more information regarding the exception.

Comment: Yes, it seems that there is an error with the proxy :"Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). )"

Comment: Good. Then that's a lead for you, know the cause of the TMG thingy :)

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot for your hint :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the Web.config. A proxy tag was added and the web service request fails because proxy credentials are not included.  Simply removing the proxy section solved the problem.